# Batch Toggle Switches with color implemented

Tags: batch-file, colors, switch-statement

So I have this simple menu with choice switches that can be toggled from yes and no just by selecting either "1" or "2" on the keyboard and that works fine but I'm trying to implement a color function to make the toggle outputs show as either Red for no or green for yes, Here's my menu code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "option1=no"
set "option2=no"
set "startScript=0"
:menu
cls
echo]
echo]
echo Select an option:
echo 1 - Toggle Option 1 [!option1!]
echo 2 - Toggle Option 2 [!option2!]
echo 3 - Start Script
echo 4 - Exit

choice /c 1234 /n /t 1000 /d 4
set "choice=%errorlevel%"

if %choice%==1 (
    if "!option1!"=="yes" (
        set "option1=no"
    ) else (
        set "option1=yes"
    )
    goto menu
) else if %choice%==2 (
    if "!option2!"=="yes" (
        set "option2=no"
    ) else (
        set "option2=yes"
    )
    goto menu
) else if %choice%==3 (
    set "startScript=1"
    cls
    echo Starting the script with the selected options...
    rem Add your script code here

    if "!option1!"=="yes" (
        call :function1
    )

    if "!option2!"=="yes" (
        call :function2
    )

    echo Done
    pause
    set "startScript=0"  REM Reset the startScript variable
    goto menu
) else if %choice%==4 (
    exit /b
)

goto menu

:function1
echo Function 1 is running...
rem Add your code for function 1 here
goto :eof

:function2
echo Function 2 is running...
rem Add your code for function 2 here
goto :eof
```

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Windows 10 and Windows 11 can use VT100 escape sequences, but previous versions have to abuse `findstr` to get inline color.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and I already have a color function for outputting multiple colors on the same line I just don't know how to implement it because it was used for just echoing sentences with multiple colors

Comment: If you're using the escape sequences, add them to the option values, like `set "option1=ESC[31mnoESC[0m"` or `set "option1=ESC[32myesESC[0m"`.

Comment: Would this script work on a fresh copy of windows 10? I believe I saw this solution when I was troubleshooting with ChatGPT and it said i needed to install something for ANSI which won't work as this script will be for when i wipe my computer.

Comment: That would depend upon which specific build of Windows 10 it was, and whether 'fresh' means an installation source which does not preconfigure the 'legacy' console.

Comment: The version of Windows 10 that does not have VT100 support predates the version of Windows 10 that is currently available for download from Microsoft. I would consider this a non-issue.

Comment: I'm obviously not very experience in batch file scripting I've seen this work in another script that uses a couple of call functions to produce the color when toggling the yes and no functions but I can't figure out how they work cause the script is like a couple thousand lines. Something like ":colorprep" and set prepparedcolor=1 "set "_cBlu="44;97m""

Comment: My apologies, after about an hour and a half of stuffing around with it I finally got it working with my function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for anyone who experiences this problem in the future:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "option1=no"
set "option2=no"
set "option3=no"
set "startScript=0"

:menu
cls
echo]
echo]
if "!option1!"=="yes" (
call :c 07 "    Option1" & call :c 02 " [!option1!] " /n
) else ( 
if "!option1!"=="no" (
call :c 07 "    Option1" & call :c 04 " [!option1!] " /n
)
 )
echo     test [!option2!]
echo     test [!option3!]
echo     Start Script
echo     Exit

choice /c 1234 /n /t 1000 /d 4
set "choice=%errorlevel%"

if %choice%==1 (
    if "!option1!"=="yes" (
    set "option1=no" 
    if "!option1!"=="yes" (
    call :c 02 "!option1!" (
        
)
    ) else (
        set "option1=yes"
    )
    goto menu
) else if %choice%==2 (
    if "!option2!"=="yes" (
        set "option2=no"
    ) else (
        set "option2=yes"
    )
    goto menu
) else if %choice%==3 (
    if "!option3!"=="yes" (
        set "option3=no"
    ) else (
        set "option3=yes"
    )
    goto menu
) else if %choice%==4 (
    set "startScript=1"
    cls
    echo]
    echo Starting the script with the selected options...
    ping localhost -n 3 >nul

    if "!option1!"=="yes" (
        call :function1
    )

    if "!option2!"=="yes" (
        call :function2
    )

    if "!option3!"=="yes" (
        call :function3
    )

    echo Done
    pause
    set "startScript=0"  REM Reset the startScript variable
    goto menu
) else if %choice%==5 (
    exit /b
)

goto menu

:function1
cls
Tree
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto :eof

:function2
cls
dir/s
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto :eof

:function3
cls
echo Hello
pause >nul
goto :eof





:c
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:colorPrint Color  Str  [/n]
setlocal
set "s=%~2"
call :colorPrintVar %1 s %3
exit /b

:colorPrintVar  Color  StrVar  [/n]
if not defined DEL call :initColorPrint
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd .
':
cd \
set "s=!%~2!"
:: The single blank line within the following IN() clause is critical - DO NOT REMOVE
for %%n in (^"^

^") do (
  set "s=!s:\=%%~n\%%~n!"
  set "s=!s:/=%%~n/%%~n!"
  set "s=!s::=%%~n:%%~n!"
)
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%s in ("!s!") do (
  if "!" equ "" setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
  if %%s==\ (
    findstr /a:%~1 "." "\'" nul
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  ) else if %%s==/ (
    findstr /a:%~1 "." "/.\'" nul
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  ) else (
    >colorPrint.txt (echo %%s\..\')
    findstr /a:%~1 /f:colorPrint.txt "."
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  )
)
if /i "%~3"=="/n" echo(
popd
exit /b


:initColorPrint
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H&for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%A %%A"
<nul >"%temp%\'" set /p "=."
subst ': "%temp%" >nul
exit /b


:cleanupColorPrint
2>nul del "%temp%\'"
2>nul del "%temp%\colorPrint.txt"
>nul subst ': /d
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /A "lastOpt=3, lastMenu=lastOpt+2"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%lastOpt%) do set "option[%%i]=no"
set "startScript=0"

set "options="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%lastMenu%) do set "options=!options!%%i"

set "toggle[no]=yes"
set "toggle[yes]=no"

set "color[no]=04"
set "color[yes]=02"

:menu
cls
echo]
echo]
echo Select an option:
for /L %%i in (1,1,%lastOpt%) do (
   for %%a in (!option[%%i]!) do (
      call :c 07 "    Option%%i" & call :c !color[%%a]! " [%%a] " /n
   )
)
echo     Start Script
echo     Exit

choice /c %options% /n /t 1000 /d %lastMenu%
set "choice=%errorlevel%"

if %choice% leq %lastOpt% (
    for %%a in (!option[%choice%]!) do set "option[%choice%]=!toggle[%%a]!"
    goto menu
) else if %choice% lss %lastMenu% (
    set "startScript=1"
    cls
    echo Starting the script with the selected options...
    rem Add your script code below each :function# label

    for /L %%i in (1,1,%lastOpt%) do (
        if "!option[%%i]!" == "yes" (
            call :function%%i
        )
    )

    echo Done
    pause
    set "startScript=0"  & REM Reset the startScript variable
    goto menu
)
exit /B
```

Further details at: [arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: Hi. Works this for you?